# How to control the action of pressing the previous page on a browser

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, browser

After testing my application i completed a form with some value , saved then wanted to add another person to the list. but when halfway the form i changed my mind and i press the return button on the browser but then something weird happens. the data from the previous form gets loaded instead of a return to the previous page(should be a list of persons).

How do you prevent this from happening?

```
  Function AddPersoon(subdienstid As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim viewModel As New PersoonViewModel
        ViewData("Persoon.rijbewijsId") = ConvertToSelectlistItemList(_iSubDienstService.GetAllRijbewijzen(), 1)
        ViewData("Persoon.PersoonStatusId") = ConvertToSelectlistItemList(_iSubDienstService.GetAllPersoonStatussen(), 1)
        Return View(viewModel)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function AddPersoon(subdienstid As Integer, model As PersoonViewModel) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            Try
                _iSubDienstService.AddPersoonTo(subdienstid, model)
                Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With {.id = subdienstid})
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
        ViewData("Persoon.rijbewijsId") = ConvertToSelectlistItemList(_iSubDienstService.GetAllRijbewijzen(), model.Persoon.RijbewijsId)
        ViewData("Persoon.PersoonStatusId") = ConvertToSelectlistItemList(_iSubDienstService.GetAllPersoonStatussen(), model.Persoon.PersoonStatusId)
        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to control the action of pressing the previous page on a browser

This is pure javascript, as there are a method that you can hook up called `onBeforeUnload` that fires when a user closes or moves to other page in the browser history.

I would recommend that you add a script like (and assuming you're using jQuery):

```
var msg = "You're about to leave this page, all changes will not been save.\n" +
          "Are you sure you want to leave?";

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
    if( confirm(msg) ) 
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

Live [example](http://jsbin.com/urihi5/edit).

Hope it helps.